# I get errors for including vector

Tags: visual-studio, cmath

I'm trying to write a simple program to display shapes using 3dCoin
however when starting to debug the program it gives me 51 errors in cmath file in which I did not change anything in it since it is a standard file.

```
#include <Inventor/Win/SoWin.h>
#include <Inventor/Win/viewers/SoWinExaminerViewer.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoSeparator.h>
#include <vector>// when I include vector it gives me the errors
int main(int, char ** argv) {
    HWND window = SoWin::init("0.off");
    if (window == NULL) exit(1);

    
    SoSeparator * root = new SoSeparator;
    root->ref();
SoWinExaminerViewer *viewer = new SoWinExaminerViewer(window);

    viewer->setSize(SbVec2s(640, 480));
    viewer->setSceneGraph(root);
    viewer->show();
    

    SoWin::show(window);
    SoWin::mainLoop();
    delete viewer;
    
    root->unref();
    return 0;
}
```

The type of errors I'm getting are:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    project c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\cmath   19
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   'type cast': cannot convert from 'float' to 'unknown-type (__cdecl *)(float)'   project c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\cmath   19

and many more.....

Can anyone help find the reason I have been trying to find a solution for a while but could not understand the reason behind such errors?

Comment: (1) Check that you are compiling as C++ code (not as C code). (2) If you're doing so, try moving your standard includes to before your others.

Answer (score 0):

I've received exactly the same error with you. More than 30 lines of cmath and also int8_t type redefinition error. I've solved this problem by putting each of ***my header files*** above ***Inventors*** and then I've put `#define HAVE_INT8_T` above everything in my source files due to the int8_t type redefinition error. Then, compile error is gone.